# How do I make my sidebar height adjust to the content?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Right now I have a sidebar that minimizes and expands along with the content beside it.
This is wrapped around a main wrapper component such that I can pass any content/component.

However, if the content is too long the sidebar height will not adjust. I have tried setting the `height` and `min-height` and it didn't do anything.

Things I have tried/have thought about:

- Faux columns however I am not sure to implement it in my use-case.
- Make the sidebar fixed however I am not sure how will the content (children of the main wrapper) will adjust if the sidebar is minimized/expanded.

Here is what is happening right now.
[image: cut sidebar]

Here is the sandbox link: [Sidebar Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/side-bar-not-adjusting-bbuee?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: you have a height:100vh, replace it with min-height:100vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Make the sidebar fixed however I am not sure how will the content
>   (children of the main wrapper) will adjust if the sidebar is
>   minimized/expanded.

To achieve this you need to create a global state with `useContext`, to adjust two separate components. And then change the **active** class of the parent element **.content-wrapper**. This will be a trigger the *.sidebar*, *.sidebar-btn* and *.content* components. Make some css changes to the css file.

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: Put the code here... Your sandbox is not working anymore...

Answer (score 0):

On the `.content-wrapper` class replace the `height: 100vh;` with `min-height: 100vh`

Add `align-items: stretch;`

From the `.content` class remove the `height: 200vh;`

This should make the sidebar grow its hight and match the height of the content.

The reason why your current styles are not working is you have fixed height for both the elements inside flex. For the `content`, the text is much more than 200vh height and is overflowing. Giving `align-items: stretch;` to the flex parent (in this case it is the `content-wrapper`) will increase the height of the children elements to either `min-height` of the flex parent or to the height of the child (`content`) with most height if the height of the child is greater than `min-height` of the parent. For your example, if the `height: 200vh;` is not removed from the `content` then this will be the child's height that is greatest and therefore the sidebar's height will stretch till 200vh and will not extend beyond 200vh.

Answer (score 0):

You can add height:max-content; for the text, and in the css declare a variable that is equal to the height, than in the sidebar height you can set height to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In React, using something like updating on `document.body.scrollHeight` worked for me:

```
const [viewHeight, setViewHeight] = useState<
  string | number
>("100vh")

useEffect(() => {
  setViewHeight(document.body.scrollHeight)
}, [document.body.scrollHeight])

...

return <div style={{ height: viewHeight }}>...</div>
```